# Wigner image of the product of two operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wigner-transform

If we know the Wigner  image  of $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$, how do we calculate the Wigner  transform of $\hat{A}\hat{B}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just use the fundamental theorem of phase space quantization, formulated by Groenewold in 1946: for Wigner maps $\hat{A}\mapsto a(x,p)$ and $\hat{B}\mapsto b(x,p)$,
$$
\hat{A}\hat{B}~~~~\longmapsto ~~~~  a\star b  ~, \\
(a \star b)(x,p) = \frac{1}{\pi^2 \hbar^2} \! \int \!a(x+x',p+p') b(x+x'',p+p'') \exp{\left(\tfrac{2i}{\hbar}(x'p''-x''p')\right)} ~  dx' dp' dx'' dp'' ,
$$
a highly non-local convolution.

(This integral form of Groenewold's *-product is due to G Baker, *Phys Rev* 109 (1958) 2198-2206.)

Comment: Where can I find a proof that WignerTrans[AB] = a*b?

Comment: In all phase-space QM books, including [our textbook](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/a.pdf), [A Concise Treatise on Quantum Mechanics in Phase Space](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/8870),  eqns (117-119), the Fundamental Theorem of the formulation.